# Current through a diode changes for the same forward voltage in two circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, ltspice, current-source

In LTspice IV, I am simulating a 1N914 diode behavior in response to a variable current source in two circuits. One circuit has just the current source and the diode, and the other has the current source and a the diode connected in parallel with a 1 kilo Ohms resistor. I vary the current out of the current source from 0 mA to 2 mA, plotting the forward voltage across the diode on the left and the current through it on the right, both on the vertical axis, versus the current out of the current source on the horizontal axis.

[image]

As shown in the picture, when I put the horizontal cursor line at the voltage where the forward voltage (V(D1)) is almost 540 mV, different values of current through the diode appear in each circuit ( I(D1) ).
Shockley equation tells that if the forward voltage is constant, then the forward current must still the same.

Comment: But you havent placed the cursor on the right spot, so we can't see what is the current @ voltage.

Comment: Current goes **through.**  Voltage is measured **across.**

Comment: You are measuring voltage **across** the parallel combination of a diode and a 1k resistor and comparing that to the voltage across just a diode at the same current source current.  In a parallel circuit, the current splits between the paths.  This changes the current through the diode and results in a different measured forward voltage for the same source current.

Comment: Place a current meter to measure current through the diodes.  I think you will find better agreement between the two circuits if you compare measured currents and voltages.  Though probably not identicle.

Comment: @JRE The current meter is chosen correctly. Otherwise both the blue lines wouldn't be called I(D1).

Comment: @JRE I know that a current passes through an element and a voltage is developed across it, I think that you understand what I mean. It is just a mistake.

Comment: @JRE If I make the voltage across the diode in either circuit constant (whether it is in parallel to a resistor or not), Shokley equation results in a constant current through the diode. Which is not the case in the image.

Comment: Again, your cursor is in wrong place, and you are taking wrong results. Place a cursor where green line is itersected, then look where blue is intersected (cursor) and then take the current value at right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at wrong place. Take result on right scale as depicted.

[image]

Comment: You are right, that is the mistake here. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer is correct, then please mark it as accepted.